# probability generating function of a sum and its expected value

Tags: probability-theory

The questions don't seem to be that hard but I think that I'm missing something...

**Question:**

> N assumes values in the nonnegative integers.
>
> (a) Show that $\frac{g_n(t)-1}{t-1}=\sum^\infty_{k=0}P(N>k)t^k$ for
>   $|t|<1$
>
> (b) Show that $E[N] = \sum^\infty_{k=0}P(N>k)$

**Part (a)**

I did the following:

$\sum^\infty_{k=0}P(N>k)t^k= \sum^\infty_{k=0}(1-P(N\leq k))t^k= \sum^\infty_{k=0}(t^k-P(N\leq k)t^k)$.

The first term in the sum can be written as a fraction and the second term shouldn't be a problem. Thus:

$\sum^\infty_{k=0}t^k = \frac{1}{1-t}$ for $|t|<1$

$\sum^\infty_{k=0}P(N\leq k)t^k=\sum^\infty_{k=0}(P(N=k)t^k + P(N<k)t^k) = g_n(t) + \sum^\infty_{k=0}P(N<k)t^k$.

Giving us:

$\frac{1}{1-t}+g_n(t)+\sum^\infty_{k=0}P(N<k)t^k$.

The problem is that I don't know how to deal with the third term.

**Part (b)**

I took the derivative of the sum with respect to t and took t as equal to one getting:

$\sum^\infty_{k=0}P(N<k)kt^{k-1}$

with $t=1$ leads to $t^{k-1} = 1$ leading to $k = 1$. Thus giving :

$E[N]=\sum^\infty_{k=0}P(N<k)$.

I assume that I've done and assumed correctly on part (b) but I'm apparently missing something elementary on part (a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you have

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(N>k)t^k = \frac{1}{1-t} - g_{n}(t) - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(N<k)t^k \\$ ?

In which case the following "result" might help... If it checks out.

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(N<k)t^k = \frac{t}{1-t}g_{n}(t) \\$

and here's why

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(N<k)t^k & = P(N<0) + P(N<1)t + P(N<2)t^2 + \cdots \\
P(N<k) & = P(N<k-2) + P(N=k-1) \\
& = P(N<0) + P(N=0) + P(N=1) + ... + P(N=k-1) \\
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(N<k)t^k & = P(N<0)(1+t+t^2+...) + P(N=1)(t+t^2+...)+ P(N=2)(t^2+...) + \cdots \\ & = \frac{P(N<0)}{1-t} + \frac{t}{1-t}P(N=0) + \frac{t^2}{1-t}P(N=1) + \frac{t^3}{1-t}P(N=2) + \cdots \\ & = \frac{t}{1-t}g_{n}(t) \\ \end{align}$$

Note that I've set $P(N < 0)=0$ on the basis that $N$ is a non-negative integer.

EDIT: Response to part B

I'm not 100% sure where the expression you started with has come from, I'm guessing you wanted to use the result of part A and there's just some typos. Either way I'd start part B by simply stating the definition of the expected value of $N$.

$$E[N] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(N=k)k$$

The rest will follow from a similar method to Part A, by expanding the sum and noting that $$P(N>k) = P(N=k+1) + P(N=k+2) + \cdots$$

Note, you can also show that, $g'(1) = E[N]$, however I'm not sure if that's really required for your answer.

Comment: Yes! I wrote it down wrong...it was late and I had a fever coming for me...Thank you anyways!

Also I assume because you didn't comment on the b part that my answer is correct?

Comment: @Drwk I hope you get well soon. I've included some suggestions about how to proceed with part B in an Edit to my post, I can't say I followed your argument unfortunately so I won't comment on your answer.

Comment: I've noticed that my post is full of typos...but on part B i used the simple fact that g'(1) = E(N). But thank you anyways I'll mark your answer!